# error... Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.... with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code. The error in Chrome is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token". I am building an online "code checker/designer" similar to codepen just for fun(practice).

I'm trying to get the user data from a textarea(the html, css and js) and display it in an iframe on the same page. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$("textarea").on("change keyup paste", function() {
    $("iframe").contents().find("html").html("<html><head><style type='text/css'>" +
        $("#cssPanel").val() +
        "</style></head><body>" +
        $("#htmlPanel").val() +
        "</body></html>");
});
```

The below works but only for html displaying in the iframe. As soon as I add the above code I get the error and nothing works/displays in the iframe.

```
$("textarea").on("change keyup paste", function() {
    $("iframe").contents().find("html").html($("#htmlPanel").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#htmlPanel").val()` instead of this try `$("#htmlPanel").innerHTML`

Comment: I have tried this and I still get the syntax error :(!

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me:
Please check:
http://jsfiddle.net/8j2u63zw/20/

```
CSS CODE :<textarea type"text" id="cssPanel">p {border-style: dotted dashed solid double;}</textarea>
HTML CODE : <textarea type"text" id="htmlPanel"><p><b>Test HTML</b></p></textarea>
<iframe>
  <html>

  </html>
</iframe>

$("textarea").on("change keyup paste", function(){
   $("iframe").contents().find("html").html("<html><head><style type='text/css'>" + $("#cssPanel").val() + "</style></head><body>" + $("#htmlPanel").val() + "</body></html>");});
```

Comment: Thank you for showing it to me. I think my error may be somewhere else then. I will update this post when I find it. I have checked everything a 1000 times. but I guess I will have to go back and keep looking.

Comment: Check if the CSS you are passing from cssPanel is correct syntactically. That can be a cause too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are running Live Server from visual studio code. somehow it just wouldnt translate the code for some reason (http://127.0.0.1:5500/ - just wont work). Try running the file directly from your explorer instead. (file:///testcode/index.html)